# How does FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

It doesn't return a view. In fact, the Action still needs to return a view after calling this ... so what's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use the `FormsAuthentication` system, you'll want to switch to this line (which implicitly uses the `returnUrl` parameter).

```
return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(model.UserName, true));
```

You will get the URL that `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` would have used, but you will explicitly bail from the action method with a `RedirectResult` instead.

#### Note

If you go this route, you'll want to put a `defaultUrl` parameter in the forms auth web.config line in case someone goes directly to your login page (or they pass in a `redirectUrl` that doesn't pass FormsAuthentication's security restrictions). Without overriding the default, bad URLs will be redirected to `~/default.aspx`. In most MVC apps, that will likely 404.

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="2880">
```

#### Alternative

If you spin up a new MVC 3 sample "Internet Application", you will find a `LogOn` action method that handles a `returnUrl` similar to what `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` does internally.

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\")) {
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
else {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what it says - a redirect. This is a response code sent to the browser to ask it to request another URL. That's the point at which a view is requested in MVC, or a web page in straight ASP.NET.

Comment: But what about the Action's return value? If the call to Redirect creates a redirect, what do I display in the meantime? A "redirect, please wait" page? Hmm, that makes sense.

Comment: Shouldn't the **server** send a Redirect response? I have the same problem and I don't want to return a View, just the redirect response from the server.